# AutoDetect numbers with currency and extract the numbers( Using any library)

Tags: java, arrays, string, currency

I am trying to solve a problem where my input looks like this :

```
String textWithCurrency = "د.ع.‏ 40,986.63";
```

In here, the currency is Arabic, from this input the number should be autodetected and extracted (leaving the symbol). Or it would be helpful if we could find the locale from this currency which would help me to reconvert them too . Does java or anyother third parties have any libraries or functions regarding this? (Writing a program is also fine but needs to be a shorter one)

I have tried some code, which I could extract numbers from it. But still need ideas like finding libraries which would make it efficient.  I have many currencies to convert, almost 180 so need a library

Answer (score 0):

Extracting currency values from strings and determining their locale can be a complex task due to the wide variety of formats and symbols used worldwide. There isn't a one-size-fits-all solution, but Java does provide the `java.util.Currency` and `java.text.NumberFormat` classes, which can assist in some aspects of this task.

However, detecting a currency symbol and converting it to a locale or currency code is not straightforward, because multiple countries might share a single currency symbol.

Given your requirements, I can suggest a two-step approach:

1. Extract the numeric value from the string.
2. Try to match the currency symbol to a locale or currency code.However, if you are going to work with 180 currencies I guess you would have problems with some of them which do not follow ASCII codes. I suggest you to create a map as follows,supposing, as you mentioned you've already managed to extract the numbers:

   ```
   public class CurrencyExtractor {
       private static Map<String, String> symbolToCurrencyCodeMap = new HashMap<>();

       static {
           // Manual mappings for specific symbols
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("د.إ"), "AED");   // United Arab Emirates Dirham
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("ر.س"), "SAR");   // Saudi Riyal
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("د.ت"), "TND");   // Tunisian Dinar
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("ل.د"), "LYD");   // Libyan Dinar
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("ر.ع."), "OMR");  // Omani Rial
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("ج.م"), "EGP");   // Egyptian Pound
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("د.ك"), "KWD");   // Kuwaiti Dinar
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("ر.ق"), "QAR");   // Qatari Riyal
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("د.ب"), "BHD");   // Bahraini Dinar
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("ل.س"), "SYP");   // Syrian Pound
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("ل.ل"), "LBP");   // Lebanese Pound
           symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.put(toUnicodeEscapeSequence("₹"), "INR");     // Indian Rupee

       }
       public static String toUnicodeEscapeSequence(String str) {
           StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

           for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
               char ch = str.charAt(i);
               result.append(String.format("\\u%04x", (int) ch));
           }

           return result.toString();
       }
       public static String extractCurrencyCode(String symbol) {
           return symbolToCurrencyCodeMap.get(symbol);
       }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String textWithCurrency = "د.ك";

       System.out.println("Currency code for symbol '" + toUnicodeEscapeSequence(textWithCurrency) + "': " + extractCurrencyCode(toUnicodeEscapeSequence(textWithCurrency)));
   }
   ```

   }

The result for the input textWithCurrency = "د.ك", would be :

[image]

Comment: CurrencyExtractor is just a part of a program, where I cannot write a seperate class for it. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Riya, if you have already a written class named CurrencyExtractor then you can rename the classname I wrote for you. as I commented in the code, I am manually defining a map, and you can fill it by the key/values interested to you.